# Visual Studio hangs on build

Tags: .net, visual-studio

When I try to build my projects in Visual Studio 2008, web sites won't build anymore, they hang on this stage:

```
------ Build started: Project: C:\...\Web\, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Validating Web Site
Building directory '/Web/Admin/Secure/'.
Building directory '/Web/Admin/'.
Building directory '/Web/Students/'.
Building directory '/Web/'.

Validation Complete
```

And I have to cancel it as it doesn't complete even after leaving it for an hour. Does anyone have any ideas on what's going on? Class libraries build fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can also often happen in the event that you have a 3rd party control that is not licensed\registered properly.  It may be attempting to display a warning\registration UI that is not making it to focus.  We have had this issue on our build servers alot.

Comment: It turns out it was an auto build number increment plugin I had that must've been hanging. I've disabled it now and my builds are fine, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help.  Build issues are annoying and quite deflating.

Comment: Follow up question: how did you know it was the plugin? what lead you to that conclusion? Did you just selectively disable each plugin?

Comment: Using ProcessExplorer will show you the process responsible for the message you cannot see (in my case a WerFault.exe that could not acquire focus)

Answer (score 9):

Try clearing out all the temporary files in

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<Framework Version>\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

This has solved similar issues for me in the past.

Comment: is `Temporary ASP.NET Files` a directory?

Answer (score 4):

I have also run into this problem in the past.  I was able to correct it by going to Build -> Clean Solution.

Answer (score 3):

renaming or deleting the SUO file seems to be a fix for this issue. My SUO file was 8mb, once I renamed and open my project back up, it ran without any crashing.

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar problem problem before.

I fixed it by making a new solution file and adding the projects again - it might be worth giving that a go.

Answer (score 2):

I basically followed the instructions for deleting the `.suo` file. However, in newer versions of VS, the `.suo` file is now inside a hidden folder `.vs` at the root solution folder level. I closed Visual Studio, then I simply renamed the `.vs` folder to `old.vs.old` and then reopened VS. Then the solution built successfully, and for some reason it also built much faster than it had been lately.

Answer (score 1):

If your .suo file has gotten too big, you may try to delete/move/rename it. VS will create a new version on your next build.

Comment: This seemed to work for me.  The new .suo file was about 100KB smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your system. It helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old thread, but I just had this problem in Visual Studio Community 2013 (Update 5).
Thought I would share what worked for me.

I cleared the checkbox for "Enable Code Analysis" in the Project Properties Pages, clicked OK, clicked save-all. Build completed at normal speed after this.

The code analysis seemed to be hanging during the Building Directory stage.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Turns out it was with a User Control I created to be transparent. While I was figuring it out, I accidentally had it invalidating the form from the control's OnPaint method, resulting in an infinite loop of painting. VS would never even start building if that control was present in any of the open designers, though it would lock everything out as if it were building. I couldn't update the designers with a fixed control because the control wouldn't build.

My Answer: Take out the painting loop, close the designers, rebuild.

Oh, designer...

Answer (score 0):

If you're a SharePoint developer, and have installed SPDisposeCheck, make sure that 'Execute after build' is switched off.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Close Visual Studio, open your project in file explorer, delete bin and obj folders from your project. (If you have more than one project delete these two files from each project.) This worked for me in the same situation.

Answer (score -1):

Ran into similar building issue today. VS 2017. Had made a few changes while doing some remote debugging on a new project. Suddenly the next time I built, it would just hang while building. VS wasn't locked up, so I could always stop it, but I had no idea what was up After some head-banging, I found that my post-build batch script was stuck running trying to synchronize built files to the remote machine for debugging, because one of the files was in use on the remote machine. Robocopy had gotten itself into an endless wait loop. What frustrated me was that I didn't discover this until after looking at the VS output window after I had stopped the build process. The errors from post-build were not showing while building, so it took me a bit before I saw the output window items.

I had also tried many of the other solutions on this page, but no luck. Hope this helps someone.